# Update SQL Server database schema using MVC .net with versioning

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

We are using a SQL Server database and web apps hosted on Azure. We maintain a database version in a table with version column.

We have added code to `Application_Start()` to check the version of database and execute the commands with higher version than current from our ASP.NET MVC app to upgrade the schema.

It was working fine until recently we noticed that in span of few seconds the `Application_Start` event got triggered again and upgrade schema functionality ran twice.

How can we prevent upgrading schema by adding some check if there is another instance upgrading schema or Is there a way to not trigger the `Application_Start` event multiple times?

We deploy the code to web app using Azure Dev Ops pipeline.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web app can be recycled for multiple reasons that are beyond your control. So placing code within Application_Start to run scripts that bring your database up to date is not optimal for the reasons you just mentioned.

Since you're already using a Dev Ops pipeline, there's a built in way to handle this as part of your deployment. Check out the Database Project type in Visual Studio. This will allow you to script all of your tables, stored procedures, views, etc in text form and keep it under source control. Then, as part of your Dev Ops pipeline, you can use the [Visual Studio Build task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build?view=azure-devops) to build your Database project and create a DACPAC as output. Then, use the [Azure SQL Database Deployment Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/sql-azure-dacpac-deployment?view=azure-devops) to pick up the DACPAC output and deploy it to your Azure SQL instance.

This way, you **KNOW** that your database is already upgraded before you finish your production deployment.

Comment: Thank you Rob! we are going to try this for the long term solution. Until that is done, we are going to add unique constraint to the version number column. So in case of parallel executions, one of the execution will fail while trying the same version number and will not cause problems with the duplicate master data records.

Comment: @SushrutParanjape One other option to consider is EF Migrations (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) . It's basically generated code that gets conditionally applied. You may feel more comfortable with this approach for the short term. But I think that the DevOps pipeline approach is superior.

Comment: Thank you Rob for the suggestion! We will look into this. We are not using EF as of now in our project. Does this require that we implement EF in our project? Or there is any alternative?

Comment: I do believe so. You do not have to actually *use* EF within your application, but I do believe that you will need to set up an EF context and keep your EF model in sync with your database. If you are not already using EF, I think this would be a huge hassle.

Comment: Thank you Rob for your inputs!